# How to get data difference between two columns

Tags: sql, singlestore

My start and finish columns are in the format
'Yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.ms'
I want the difference between the two in HH:mm:ss.ms format.
How do I go about this?

My query looks like this:

```
Select *,convert(time,   Dateadd(s,
    Datediff(s,
      A.Finish,A.Start),
       Cast('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000' as    datetime2)))as dif from(select *,dateadd(s,convert(int,left(start,10)),'1970-01-01') as Start,convert(int,left(finish,10)),'1970-01-01') as Finish from tableB)A order by dif asc
```

I've converted unix time stamps to standard format in inner query.
When I run this the start date and start time appear as '2019-12-11 15:45:20.000' and '2019-12-12 15:45:17.000' but my dif appears as '00:00:03'

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: DATEDIFF() function?

Comment: @VBoka I've added into to the question

Comment: @jarlh I've added info to the question

Answer (score 1):

Try to use TIMESTAMPDIFF() instead of datediff as you have time and second in your query.

https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/reference/sql-reference/date-and-time-functions/timestampdiff.html

You can check the syntax and example in the above link.