# Unable to get difference between 2 dates in required format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-arithmetic

My start and finish columns are in the format `Yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.ms` I want the difference between the two in `HH:mm:ss.ms` format. How do I go about this?

My query looks like this:

```
select *, convert(time, 
        Dateadd(s, 
            Datediff(s, A.Finish, A.Start), 
            Cast('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000' as datetime2)
        )
    ) as dif 
from (
    select *,
        dateadd(s,convert(int,left(start,10)),'1970-01-01') as Start,
       dateadd(s,convert(int,left(finish,10)),'1970-01-01') as Finish,     
    from tableB
) A 
order by dif asc
```

I've converted unix time stamps to standard format in inner query. When I run this the start date and start time appear as '2019-12-11 15:45:20.000' and '2019-12-12 15:45:17.000' but my dif appears as '00:00:03',which is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. There's no if or but about this. Formats apply **only** when you convert that binary value to a string, or parse a string to get a date. To format, use `CONVERT` or `FORMAT` to format the date into the format you want

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have used convert

Comment: BTW you don't need Unix timestamps either, unless you write in C or use SQLite *and* don't use any date types. All other databases have date types. Using Unix timestamps makes your code **non**-portable and far harder to read.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the data in a couple of columns is in Unix timestamp so I had to convert them to the normal date time format.There is nothing I can do about the Unix format already in the table,it comes from upstream.

Comment: If you want help, post the *actual* table schemas and sample data. YouStoring integers instead of dates is *not* common (it's a serious bug actually) so nobody would expect dates to be stored that way. Why do you use *two* epochs? Are you storing different types of timestamps perhaps?

Comment: What is your database ?

Comment: @VBoka database: ms-sql

Comment: Yesterday it was memsql ? Today is SQLServer ?

Comment: @VBoka I'm new to this forum.Must have posted it wrong yesterday.Apologize.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I had the query typed in wrong.ive corrected it now in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used two sources to try to help you:

https://www.rodolforodarte.com/2011/05/using-datediff-to-display-hhmmss/

AND

[Show datediff as seconds, milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660647/show-datediff-as-seconds-milliseconds)

Here is my result code:

```
DECLARE @START_DATE DATETIME
DECLARE @END_DATE   DATETIME
SET     @START_DATE = '2011-01-01 16:00:22.000'
SET     @END_DATE =   '2011-01-01 22:47:21.022'

SELECT    CONVERT(varchar(6), DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @START_DATE, @END_DATE)/3600000)
+ ':'
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @START_DATE, @END_DATE) % 3600000) / 60000), 2)
+ ':'
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),   ((DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @START_DATE, @END_DATE) % 3600000) % 60000) / 1000), 2)
+ ':'
+ RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (((DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @START_DATE, @END_DATE) % 3600000) % 60000) % 1000)), 3) AS 'HH:MM:SS:MS'
```

[And here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8b7e47eb7b28adeaceafb47056626090)

Comment: You do not have to accept this answer if it is not correct. First check it and then if it is ok then accept it...

Comment: i took this and modified it to my scenario,it appears to work

Comment: Ok, so now you can delete this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173109/how-to-get-data-difference-between-two-columns